# Getting list of persons using SPARQL dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using [live-dbpedia](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) to retrieve the list of persons. I am executing a **sparql query** on [live-dbpedia endpoints](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) to get the result.I have fixed the **offset and limit value** in the query and getting the records **after each 10000 attempt**. But when I was trying to execute at **580000 offset value**, **504 Gateway Time-out error** happens.

**Not Working** SPARQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?dbpedia_link str(?name) as ?label str(?label1) as ?label1 ?freebase_link WHERE {
        ?dbpedia_link rdfs:label ?label1 . 
        ?dbpedia_link foaf:name ?name .
        {
         { ?dbpedia_link rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person }                            
        }                        
        OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link owl:sameAs ?freebase_link .
        FILTER regex(?freebase_link, "^http://rdf.freebase.com") .}
        FILTER (lang(?label1) = 'en'). 
        ?dbpedia_link dcterms:subject ?sub 
        }Limit 1000
        OFFSET 580000
```

**Working** SPARQL Query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?dbpedia_link str(?name) as ?label str(?label1) as ?label1 ?freebase_link WHERE {
            ?dbpedia_link rdfs:label ?label1 . 
            ?dbpedia_link foaf:name ?name .
            {
             { ?dbpedia_link rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person }                            
            }                        
            OPTIONAL {?dbpedia_link owl:sameAs ?freebase_link .
            FILTER regex(?freebase_link, "^http://rdf.freebase.com") .}
            FILTER (lang(?label1) = 'en'). 
            ?dbpedia_link dcterms:subject ?sub 
            }Limit 1000
            OFFSET 50000
```

How to overcome this problem.

Comment: In addition to [jimkont's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26136741/1281433), note that **limit n** and **offset m** need an **order by** in order to be useful.  If there's no specified ordering, then the endpoint can return the same **n** results over and over again.  E.g., see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25147648/1281433) to [How to resolve the execution limits in Linkedmdb](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25141247/1281433).

Answer (score 4):

Put a delay between your requests. There is a rate limit in the live endpoint and this is the error you get when you exceed it. There is also a short timeout to make the service more available.

(Disclaimer: I am responsible for the service)

Comment: Thanks for responding.. How can I put `delay in sparql`? If I am executing a `query just a once`. Plz try to execute the `Non-working SPARQL query` from above, then you will get the error of gateway.

Comment: you can try the Live clone hosted by OpenLink http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql . That server has more resources and answers the query.

Comment: `@jimkont :` I need the records from the http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql endpoints only. We did some `R&D` on http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql endpoints. It is not giving proper output. It shows exception in such cases Ex.`<class 'simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError'>`

Comment: By today evening we deploy a new endpoint and the openlink cache will also be correct from now on

Comment: Have you **(@jimkont)** deployed the **new endpoint** or upgraded the previous. Because still, I am facing the `same gateway error`. As I have discussed with my colleague, he told me that don't use `filter(regular expression)` because it is taking too much time to execute the `sparql query`.

Comment: See http://www.mail-archive.com/dbpedia-discussion@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06436.html
Now you can use the OpenLink endpoint that has the same data as the official one. (the rate limits didn't change)

Comment: Sir **@jimkont**, http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql is working but when I am trying for offset 500000, it doesn't give any result. why so?